# Pygame como fazer o personagem pular

Tags: python, pygame

Estou dando meus primeiros passos no pygame, e estou tentando fazer com que o personagem do jogo pule, mas me deparei com um erro: o personagem apenas teleporta para cima e para baixo em 2 frames ele fez o movimento todo, e não consigo encontrar uma maneira eficiente de fazer com que haja uma animação completa de um pulo... alguém pode me dar uma luz?

eis o código do pulo:

```
class Luna(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.images = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join("sprites", "luna2.png")).convert_alpha(),
                       pygame.image.load(os.path.join("sprites", "luna.png")).convert_alpha(),
                       pygame.image.load(os.path.join("sprites", "luna3.png")).convert_alpha()]

        self.current_image = 0
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("sprites", "luna2.png")).convert_alpha()

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect[0] = 0
        self.rect[1] = height - 220
        self.jumping = False
        self.gravity = 10
        self.jump_height = 150

    def update(self):
        # updates walking Luna
        self.current_image = (self.current_image + 1) % 3
        self.image = self.images[self.current_image]
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (200, 200))

        if self.jumping:

            self.rect[1] -= 200 # posição no eixo y
            self.jumping = False


        else:
            while self.rect[1] < window_height:
                self.rect[1] += 1

    def jump(self):
        self.jumping = True
```

a def draw que desenha o personagem na tela:

```
def draw_window():
    window.blit(background_image, (0, 0))

    ground_group.update()
    ground_group.draw(window)

    luna_group.update()
    luna_group.draw(window)
    pygame.display.update()
```

e o loop main do pygame:

```
def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(fps)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    luna.jump()

        draw_window()
    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu estava sofrendo com a mesma coisa.
import pygame
from sys import exit
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
width, height = 544, 320

## Criando a tela

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Mais um teste de jogo')

## Criando o background

bg = pygame.image.load('imagens/parallax-forest-preview.png')
bg_rect = bg.get_rect(topleft=(0, 0))

## Criando o heroi

heroi = pygame.image.load('imagens/spellun-sprite.png').convert_alpha()
heroi_rect = heroi.get_rect(midbottom=(272, 300))

gravidade_heroi = 0

## Laço principal

while True:
# Desenha o background
screen.blit(bg, bg_rect)

```
# Evento para fechar o jogo
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        exit()

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            gravidade_heroi = -20

gravidade_heroi += 1
heroi_rect.y += gravidade_heroi

if heroi_rect.bottom >= 300:
    heroi_rect.bottom = 300

screen.blit(heroi, heroi_rect)

pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)
```

Observe a variavel clock no começo do programa e no final clock.tick(60).
Isso resolveu para mim.